# How to get individual ui-utility module using bower.json

Tags: angular-ui, bower

I'm trying to include the ui-mask utility in my projects `bower.json` file so other devs will be able to install it when running `bower install`.

I can install it manually with `bower install angular-ui-utils#bower-mask`,

but in my `bower.json` file I can't figure out the correct name/version. Should be mask-0.1.1

[Angular UI-Utils](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils)

[UI-Util Mask Module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/tree/master/modules/mask)

What I want to work in bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.x",
    "angular": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-touch": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.x",
    "at-table": "1.0.1",
    "ngDialog": "0.2.13",
    "angular-local-storage" : "0.0.7",
    "angular-ui-utils#bower-mask" : "0.1.1"  <- This should work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `bower install angular-ui-utils#bower-mask` you instruct bower to look for angular-ui-utils with a "bower-mask" version.
A version in this case is actually a git tag, branch or commit hash (when bower is using a git resolver).
Since the the [angular-ui/ui-utils](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils) repository has a [bower-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/tree/bower-mask) branch it will be resolved.
If you would like to resolve bower-mask 0.1.1 you will need to find the correct tag in the Github repository. In this case this should be [mask-0.1.1](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/tree/mask-0.1.1), so what you need in `bower.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-utils" : "mask-0.1.1"
  }
}
```

In the bower output you should see:

```
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#mask-0.1.1
bower download      https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/archive/mask-0.1.1.tar.gz
```